# Powerpoint Notes Section formatting VBA

Tags: powerpoint

Using the following code to format the notes section of every slide to a pictured bulleted list works nearly every time, but in select presentations will give the error:

Placeholders (unknown member) : Integer is out of range. 2 is not in the valid range of 1 to 1.

This does not seem to be linked to any number of slides, whether or not the notes sections already contain text in them, etc.

```
Sub Button1()
  Dim intSlide As Integer

With ActivePresentation

For intSlide = 1 To .Slides.Count

With ActivePresentation.Slides(intSlide).NotesPage. _
            Shapes.Placeholders(2).TextFrame.TextRange
    With .ParagraphFormat.Bullet
        .Type = ppBulletPicture
        .Picture ("/Applications/Microsoft Office/picture.JPG")
        .RelativeSize = 1.4
    End With
     End With
Next intSlide
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you're not just using the program interface to set the bullets in the Notes Master. That's a lot easier than writing VBA.

If a notes page has only 1 placeholder instead of 2, that error would occur. Here's a more robust routine that checks the shape type and whether it actually contains text or not:

```
Sub Button1()
    Dim oSlide As Slide
    Dim oShape As Shape
    
    For Each oSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShape In oSlide.NotesPage.Shapes
            If oShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                If oShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
                    If oShape.HasTextFrame Then
                        If oShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
                            With oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet
                                .Type = ppBulletPicture
                                .Picture ("C:/picture.png")
                                .RelativeSize = 1.4
                            End With
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! The reason being is that setting bullets with a custom picture via this add in is faster than having to reload said picture into a new presentation each time :)

Comment: Create a template for new presentations. In that template, open View>Notes Master and format the text with picture pullets. Then every new presentation from that template already has the correct formatting.